# Struggling to update records in a database (Swift 4.2)

Tags: arrays, swift, database, loops

I'm new to coding (my way of saying please don't shoot me because I don't know how to solve my issue, I'm learning as fast as I can, I'm reading books, trying out code, doing a course, etc).  I'm looking for guidance only and am not expecting someone to hand me the code, however, pointers or how I should structure the query below would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Xcode 10.2 with Swift 5.  I am using CoreData and have a database entity (known as MyDB).  Within the database entity, I have about 20 fields one of which is status.  status is an Int16 field and needs to hold a value of 0, 1 or 2.

I have already created records where every record 'status' is set to a value of 0.  I am able to set the value of 'status' to 1 when a user clicks on a checkmark within my app (and it saves it to persistent storage).

Where I am getting stuck is I want to be able to create a function (triggered by an IBAction) that then looks at each row of the database (array-in-memory), looks at the status field, and if the status field is set to 1 then I want to set the status field to 2.  Then when all the fields are updated I simply write the database context (ie. save the database)

Many things with no luck.... and lots of errors...

Unfortunately, I don't have any examples of code as everything I try is throwing up errors.  However, I will try to describe what I think I need to achieve...

```
@IBAction func folderButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    loop until the end of the array-in-memory {
        if status-field at array-in-memory(at: indexPath.row) == 1 {
            let status-field at array-in-memory(at: indexPath.row) = 2
        }  
    }

    save the database (ie. write to context)
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to find and do a tutorial on core data, maybe something like [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Want to save the data in loop?